# Restrictions on local variable usage in C++?

Tags: c++, oop, scope

I had a few questions in a technical interview that I thought I knew, but wanted to double-check (they said I passed it, but I was unsure about these):

1. A variable declared inside a Class Method... Can that be used outside of that method, like for instance in another method? *(I said no)*
2. Can a variable declared inside a method be passed as a parameter to another method?
   *(I said yes but I wasn't sure)*

---

This is for an entry-level C++ position and I'm used to C, so I wanted to double-check my understanding of C++/OO concepts.

Comment: Maybe it is an interview for an internship.  Maybe he is proficient with other languages and they plan on teaching him C++.  He never said what the interview was *for*.

Comment: He just graduated or is in the process of graduating.  C++ is a daunting language with a kitchen sink approach of throwing everything in.  For first interviews it's perfectly alright to doubt yourself.  Not finding out the answer, like by asking on SO, is worse than asking it.  Someone who is willing to ask and learn is worth 1000 engineers who are cocksure but stupid.

Comment: Wow Im glad everyone is so supportive here. Regardless I was RIGHT basically on both of my answers, and it's for an Entry level position. So yes beginner level stuff, but.....ENTRY level position. I was just double checking

Comment: It is offensive.....because First of all, I was double CHECKING my correct answers. Secondly, C++ isn't what I used most of my life so Object Oriented Stuff is NEWISH to me. Not everyone goes to the same school, and things get taught differently. And Thirdly is was just a negative comment that wasn't needed.

Comment: @EdSwangren, @Sauron, please take this discussion to Meta: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/76808/why-do-people-bother-to-reply-just-to-insult-you - it adds nothing but noise to the question.

Comment: This is chapter 1 intro to C++ stuff.  I'm sorry if I offended you, it wasn't my intent, and I applaud you for asking the question and wanting to learn.  However, this has nothing to do with "object oriented stuff", and my point still stands that you can't expect to work a position that would require you to learn the language from scratch on the job.

Comment: Im not gonna get into it any more. Classes are not Chapter 1 intro stuff, and I've had to pick up languages and apply them all throughout school. Double checking a question doesn't hurt anyone.

Comment: @Ed Swangren http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76808/why-do-people-bother-to-reply-just-to-insult-you

Comment: Taken there, sorry for the argument I seem to have started here.

Comment: @Sauron: I think Ed's point is that if you have some programming experience already (as a CS major), you already know the answers to these questions. There's nothing *at all* wrong with double-checking yourself, and you got some excellent answers that already cover the technical stuff. My point (and presumably his as well) is that C++ is no different in this regard than any other language, regardless of its object-oriented aspects. It doesn't have anything to do with classes and objects; that's a whole *new* horizon of confusion! Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. A variable within a class method, that's instantiated within that method and wholly contained within that method, can only be used within that method.  Its lifetime is finite.  **Edit**: to clarify, I'm not saying it can't be passed to another function call within the function scope and I'm not talking about instantiating a member variable or static variable.
2. Yes, you can pass it to another method if that method is called from within the method it exists.  Why?  Because its lifetime it tied to the parent method, not the one that is called from within the method.

Let me illustrate:

```
//aVar does not exist.
int foo(){
   int aVar = 1; //it's been born
   cout << doSomething(aVar); // still alive

   return aVar; //still alive but a copy is being returned from the function.  Not aVar itself!
} // it's dead, man
```

Comment: static variables, pointers, and classes with the relevant constructors and operator= can all be accessed from outside the function (if passed).

Comment: @Chris Lutz that's why I said wholly owned and contained... Oh, I see the confusion.

Comment: Thanks first of all for A. Not being a jerk when answering me, and B. Explaining and using it in context. I felt like I was correct but I always wanted to make double sure.

Comment: @Sauron Don't ever stop asking and learning.  Also, good luck on your career and future interviews.

Answer (score 1):

1. Normally a variable's lifetime is inside the block it's declared in. So at the end of the scope it is destroyed.
   **BUT** there's the case of **Static Local Variable** which is declared inside a method, but the value is saved in memory after the block is finished. Every call to that function will "see" the value of that variable. So, you could have a trick question, that the variable **CAN** be used in another instance of that method.
2. Yes you can pass it.

Answer (score 1):

Contrary to popular belief, a variable declared in a member function *can* be used in another member function. There are two obvious routes to this.

The first is if that member function calls another member function, passing a pointer or reference to that variable to the second member function. The variable exists from the time the first member function is called until it exits from that call; if it calls some other function during that time, that other code can use the variable (if the member function does something to give it access).

The second is if you're dealing with a *static* variable defined in a member function. This is (for one example) the essence of the Meyers singleton. A static variable is defined in a member function, and not only other members of the singleton, but in fact all the rest of the program that accesses the singleton object use the static variable defined in that member function.

For the second question, you're right -- a variable defined in a member function is pretty much like any other local variable. It can be passed as a parameter, just like anything else.

Answer (score 0):

First Question: Yes, you are correct.  Variables declared within the scope of a class method are only valid in that scope.  When the method exits, that variable loses scope and is no longer usable.

Second Question: Yes, the method can call another method, using that locally scoped variable.  The variable remains in scope and is usable through the duration of the second function call.

Answer (score 0):

> First of all.....a variable declared
>   inside a Class Method....can that be
>   used outside of that method, like for
>   instance in another method

In C++, no.

> Secondly, can a variable declared
>   inside a method be passed as a
>   parameter for another method?

In C++, in a non-concurrent application, yes. In the case of concurrency and the receiving function takes its parameter by reference you must make sure the object you pass doesn't destruct while the receiving function uses it.

Answer (score 0):

```
First of all.....a variable declared inside a Class Method....
can that be used outside of that method, 
like for instance in another method
```

Sure.  For example,

```
class Base {
 public:
  static Base *create_instance() {
    static int variable_declared_inside_class_method = 0;
    return new Base(variable_declared_inside_class_method);
  }

  Base(int &var_) : var(var_) {}

  int inc_var() {
    var++;  // this method uses variable_declared_inside_class_method 
  }

 private:
  int &var;
};
```

Note that `variable_declared_inside_class_method` does not live on the stack.  This is why it works here.

```
Secondly, can a variable declared inside a method be passed as a parameter 
for another method?
```

Absolutely.